# Getting MultiDex error while adding dependency for gcm and onesignal push notification

Tags: android

Problem: When I add the below dependencies in build.gradle, I am getting a multiDex error. I know this happens if I have unnecessary dependency but I am not able to sort it out. I am doing this for one single push notification in my app.

I added following dependencies to my build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
```

Before this my app was working fine. All of tthe dependecies in my gradle file are listed below (including the above dependencies)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.2.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
}
```

Any help on how to fix this?

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'

Do you require full version of play services ? can you try removing it(it might as well reduce the need of multidex altogether) ?

Comment: giving it a try. I will let you know in a minute

Comment: Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;  I M GETTING THIS ERROR

Comment: I think its support jar you are including. This is already defined with appcompat right ? Can you try to remove     compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')

Comment: did it work after removing support jar?

Comment: Nope, It doesn't. Same error popping again and again..If I remove all what I added and just keep compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar' then it works but I don't receive push notification anymore.

Comment: It must be one the dependencies which are added as jar files through compile files..

Comment: Can you try by removing one by one and see which is causing the exact error.

Comment: I removed top 2 dependencies  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar'). It fixed the error. But still I am not getting Push notification which I think is now a separate issue. Problem with dependency is solved. I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is just to add Gcm. you dont need those many dependencies. Especially google play services full version.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

Its always good to add smaller dependencies which fits your usecase such as

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
```

If you still are still exceeding 65k limit and need multidex, you must enable in your module gradle file.

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

in your module grandle file in defaultConfig.

Along with this, its better enable proguard to keep following attributes as well to make sure you dont bloat up the apk size

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
```

Note that enabling proguard has its own problems which you will have deal with by carefully reviewing proguard-rules.pro

Comment: Totally agree with @Ramesh, only use what you need, you can get more  info on the public documentation about *how to 
setting up google play services* https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 0):

if you can't solve your application's dependencies. 
multi dex application supporting can be solution for that.

http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html